# Is Caliphate as same as Islamic government or are they different?

Tags: government, terminology, islam

- [Essence of Islamic governments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_state#Essence_of_Islamic_governments)

the above Wikipedia link says that:

> (...) most Muslim scholars are of the opinion that Islamic al-Shura
> should consist of the following:
>
> - Meeting or consultation that follows the teachings of Islam.
> - Consultation following the guidelines of the Quran and the Sunnah.
> - There is a leader elected among them to head the meeting.
> - The discussion should be based on mushawarah and mudhakarah.
> - All members are given fair opportunity to voice out their opinions.
> - The issue should be of maslahah ammah or public interest.
> - The voices of the majority are accepted, provided it does not violate the teachings of the Quran or Sunnah.

Is this the same as [Caliphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliphate)? Is "Caliphate" as same as the "Islamic government" or are they different?

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, a Caliphate is a political system under a caliph: a proper successor to the prophet Muhammed. Not every islamic government would consider its leader a successor to Muhammed — e.g., neither Saudi Arabia nor Iran call their leaders caliph — so in that sense a Caliphate is a particular form of Islamic government.

Comment: Nonetheless more states claimed to be a caliphate, chiefly the Ottomans https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Caliphate